# PHP SNMPv3 credentials test loop failing

Tags: php, snmp

I have an array of credentials objects. If I loop over them attempting to retrieve an OID using SNMPv3, it fails - but only if there are bad credentials before good credentials in the array. If the good credentials come first, it works. If the bad come first, even the good credentials after them fail. Sample code below.

If I change the order of the credentials added to the array, it works if good come first.

If I have **only** good credentials in the array, it works.

If the bad come before the good in the array, even the good credentials fail.

Essentially the same code works fine for SNMPv2 or even SNMPv1, but not for v3.

Any assistance appreciated.

```
<?php
$retries = 1;
$timeout = 5000000;
$ip = '1.2.3.4';
$oid = '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0';
$credentials = array();

$credentials[] = json_decode('{
    "credentials":
    {
        "authentication_passphrase": "some_bad_auth_passphrase",
        "authentication_protocol": "SHA",
        "privacy_passphrase": "some_bad_priv_passphrase",
        "privacy_protocol": "AES",
        "security_level": "authNoPriv",
        "security_name": "good_username"
    },
    "name": "Bad SNMPv3"
}');

$credentials[] = json_decode('{
    "credentials":
    {
        "authentication_passphrase": "good_passphrase",
        "authentication_protocol": "SHA",
        "privacy_passphrase": "good_passphrase",
        "privacy_protocol": "AES",
        "security_level": "authPriv",
        "security_name": "good_username"
    },
    "name": "Good SNMPv3"
}');


foreach ($credentials as $credential) {
    # sample command only to confirm credentials used
    echo 'snmpget -v3 -l ' . $credential->credentials->security_level  .
    ' -u ' . $credential->credentials->security_name .
    ' -a ' . $credential->credentials->authentication_protocol .
    ' -A ' . $credential->credentials->authentication_passphrase .
    ' -x ' . $credential->credentials->privacy_protocol .
    ' -X ' . $credential->credentials->privacy_passphrase .
    ' ' . $ip . ' ' . $oid . "\n";

    $session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_3, $ip, $credential->credentials->security_name, $timeout, $retries);
    $session->setSecurity(
        $credential->credentials->security_level,
        $credential->credentials->authentication_protocol,
        $credential->credentials->authentication_passphrase,
        $credential->credentials->privacy_protocol,
        $credential->credentials->privacy_passphrase,
        '',
        ''
    );

    $result = @$session->get($oid);
    print_r($session->getError());

    $session->close();
    unset($session);

    if (!empty($result)) {
        print $result . "\n";
        break;
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Example output with bad credentials first.

```
mark@dev:~$ php snmp3_test.php 
snmpget -v3 -l authNoPriv -u bad_username -a SHA -A EC2=bad -x AES -X EC2=bad 1.2.3.4 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
Fatal error: Authentication failure (incorrect password, community or key)
snmpget -v3 -l authPriv -u good_username -a SHA -A good_auth_pass -x AES -X good_priv_pass 1.2.3.4 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
Fatal error: Authentication failure (incorrect password, community or key)
```

Example output where good credentials are first in the array.

```
mark@dev~$ php snmp3_test.php 
snmpget -v3 -l authPriv -u good_username -a SHA -A good_auth_passphrase -x AES -X good_priv_pass 1.2.3.4 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
STRING: "Linux machine_name 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u2 (2020-11-11) x86_64"
```

Comment: Does it try all of the credentials? Is an exception thrown which makes the loop terminate?

Comment: Added output. All credentials attempted. getError thrown, but loop not terminated.

Comment: Maybe there is a server side block rule if snmp credentials are wrong! Block IP, Block user, something like this.

Comment: I'm starting to think so, however looking at the SNMP config on the target, nothing stands out.

Comment: Just tested on Windows Xampp and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: And I even added a 70second pause between attempts. No difference. But if I change the order, it works again straight away. So that suggests it's **not** the target blocking the attempt.

Comment: And FYI the app runs on both Linux and Windows, so I have to resolve it for both. I could put in a nasty work-around on Linux to shell out and run an SNMPGet from the command line, but I cannot do that on Windows (because reasons). Sigh.

Comment: I have narrowed it down a bit more. If you use the same security username for both queries (and use the bad credentials first) it breaks. If they use different usernames, the first request fails (as expected) and the second works.